# find limit by rationalizing?

Tags: limits

I'm extremely new to calculus so please excuse my lack of lingo/formatting.!
Here is the problem:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{5n^2 + 4n +2} - \sqrt{5n^2 - 2n - 1}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rationalize:

- Multiply by $$\frac{\sqrt{5n^2 + 4n +2} + \sqrt{5n^2 - 2n -
     1}}{\sqrt{5n^2 + 4n +2} + \sqrt{5n^2 - 2n - 1}}$$

  $$\left(\sqrt{5n^2 + 4n +2} - \sqrt{5n^2 - 2n -
     1}\right)\cdot\frac{\sqrt{5n^2 + 4n +2} + \sqrt{5n^2 - 2n -
     1}}{\sqrt{5n^2 + 4n +2} + \sqrt{5n^2 - 2n - 1}}$$ $$= \frac{6n+3}{\sqrt{5n^2 + 4n +2} + \sqrt{5n^2 - 2n - 1}}$$
- Now, divide numerator and denominator by $n$.

You should end up with a limit $$\frac{6}{2\sqrt 5} = \frac 3{\sqrt 5} = \frac {3\sqrt 5}{5}$$

Comment: I've done relationalization, but can't go any step forward this

Comment: Write $n = \sqrt{n^2}$ when you divide the denominator by $n$, and then you can move the term inside the radicals.

Comment: You're welcome, linna!

Answer (score 0):

Rationalizing expresion(multypling  nominator and denominator with ${ \sqrt{5n^2 + 4n +2} +\sqrt{5n^2 - 2n - 1}}$) you have $\lim_n\frac{6n+3}{ \sqrt{5n^2 + 4n +2} +\sqrt{5n^2 - 2n - 1}}$

And you have (dividing nominator and deonominator with n) that limit is 6/($\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{5}$) and that is 3/$\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Your denominator converges to $2 \sqrt{5}$, not $10$.

Comment: I saw after I had typed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Set $\dfrac1n=h\implies h\to0^+$  as $n\to\infty$

$5n^2+4n+2=\dfrac{5+4h+2h^2}{h^2}$

$\sqrt{5n^2+4n+2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{5+4h+2h^2}}{\sqrt{h^2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{5+4h+2h^2}}{+h}$ as $h>0$

So, we have $$\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt{5+4h+h^2}-\sqrt{5-2h-h^2}}h$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{(5+4h+h^2)-(5-2h-h^2)}h\cdot\dfrac1{\lim_{h\to0^+}(\sqrt{5+4h+h^2}+\sqrt{5-2h-h^2})}$$

Hope the rest can be handled easily